# How to pass the value in a toggle button in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, toggle

I have this toggle button code. How to pass the values from this toggle button by the POST method..

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label>Sold Out</label>
 <div> 
   <button data-toggle="collapse">YES</button>
   <button data-toggle="collapse">NO</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want it to perform post action immediately on button click ... or there'll be another button to submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['yesBtn'])) {
        echo "<p>".$_POST['yesBtn']."</p>";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['noBtn'])) {
        echo "<p>".$_POST['noBtn']."</p>";
    }
?>
<form action="somefile.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Sold Out</label>
        <div> 
            <button data-toggle="collapse" name="yesBtn" value="YES">YES </button>
            <button data-toggle="collapse" name="noBtn" value="NO">NO</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Or this

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Btn'])) {
        echo "<p>".$_POST['Btn']."</p>";
    }
?>
<form action="somefile.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Sold Out</label>
        <div> 
            <button data-toggle="collapse" name="btn" value="YES">YES </button>
            <button data-toggle="collapse" name="btn" value="NO">NO</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your Answer is correct. But I want to POST the value with same name attribute.

Comment: Try using the same name, if it does not work, just check if  either `yesBtn` or `noBtn` is set.

Comment: Just tried it, you could use the same value for the `name` attribute

Comment: @RaguSGR Do accept the answer if this helped you. Cheers!